# Reach webserver via SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, webserver, tunnel, bridge

I have a RaspberryPi in my private local network (example: 192.168.1.2) and I have a dedicated server (example: 99.99.99.99) from some provider. 
From my RaspberryPi I can connect to the server via ssh without trouble, the opposite situation is not possible. The RaspberryPi is not reachable from the internet. 
Now I want to reach the webserver on my RaspberryPi from the internet with some ssh brigde/tunnel. 
So if I enter the IP 99.99.99.99 in my browser, I want to see the website from the RaspberryPi. How it is possible?

Comment: You can also run a VPN over SSH. See the `SSH-BASED VIRTUAL PRIVATE NETWORKS` section from the OpenSSH `ssh` [manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&apropos=0&sec=0&arch=default&manpath=OpenBSD-current)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-R` option to ssh will permit a remote tunnel to be opened towards the ssh client.  So, if from the pi you run

```
ssh -R0.0.0.0:8080:address_of_pi:80 99.99.99.99
```

Then you will open an ssh and while that ssh is active anyone can go to `99.99.99:8080` and get to your pi.

You need to use 8080 as the port on the webserver address because the ssh process cannot bind to port 80 without being root.

Comment: Is working, thanks. But I had to add the following line in the config file (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) on the server: GatewayPorts yes